# Angular 6 - compare two observables lengths

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular2-observables

Is there a way to compare the current length of two observables?

EDIT: It is to compare the arrays withing the observables. 
I want to compare all the elements count withing them(See example below).

At the point I am trying to do it, they are already completely loaded. Not waiting on any data.

For example I want to do:

```
if (array1.length < array2.length) {
    array1.foreach(item => item.isSelected = true);
```

I tried using **pipe, map, tap**, but they resolve after some time and don't work for me. I know this might be a breaking of obserables concepts, but was wondering if there is an option to do it?

Comment: What are your observables producing? Do you want to compare the number of values emitted by the observables (see [count()](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/count.html)) or do you want to compare the size of the arrays the observable emitted (in case they are `Observable<any[]>`).

Comment: `compare the current length of two observables` ? Observables have no length

Comment: Use `map/SwicthMap` on both the observables, one inside the other and then compare the lengths..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmgdyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the resolved values of one `Observable` inside the other.

```
ob1 = of([1,2,3])
ob2 = of([1,2,3, 4]);


  foo() {
  this.ob1.pipe(
    switchMap((data1)=> {
      return this.ob2.pipe(
        map((data2) => {
          console.log(data1, data2); // will print [1,2,3] [1,2,3,4],
                                     //  which now you can compare easily
        })
      )
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmgdyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Is there a difference if I am gonna use subscribe twice instead: data1.subscribe(items => { data2.subscribe(items2 => { }) }); ?

Comment: I was doing `switchMap` just because I wanted to `subscribe` once, wan't actually waiting for `ob1` to finish before starting `ob2` as they were already loaded... There is no harm in using `subscribe` twice, unless you don't want to subscribe right away, for example you don't want to do the calculation in `foo()` but `foo()` might only be doing an `http` request to get `ob1` and `ob2` and you might be comparing the results somewhere else..

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to compare the length is the zip operator as follow:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {  zip } from 'rxjs';

const data = of([20, 21, 30, 40]);
const data1 = of([22, 25, 35, 45]);

const example = zip(data, data1);
example.subscribe(val => console.log(val[0].length, val[1].length));
```