# Merging two observables when IDs are equal in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following first array (let's call it organisation array):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "id": "org1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "id": "org2"
  }
]
```

and the second array is (let's call it unit array):

```
[
  {
    "organisation_id": "org1",
    "id": "unitId1"
  },
  {
    "organisation_id": "org30",
    "id": "UnitId2"
  }
]
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "id": "org1",
    "units": [
        {
          "organisation_id": "org1",
          "id": "unitId1"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "id": "org2",
    "units": []
  }
]
```

And I want to combine these two arrays (per object) into one array of objects, and create a `units` property when `id === organisation_id`. This works when I do something like this:

```
const combOrgUnit: OrganisationAndUnit[] = [];

this.organisations.subscribe(orgList => {
  this.units.subscribe(unitList => {
    for (const org of orgList) {
      const tempComb: OrganisationAndUnit = {organisation: undefined, units: []};
      const tempUnit: Unit[] = [];
      tempComb.organisation = org;
      for (const unit of unitList) {
        if (org.id === unit.organisation_id) {
          tempUnit.push(unit);
          tempComb.units = tempUnit;
        }
      }
      combOrgUnit.push(tempComb);
    }
    console.log(combOrgUnit);
  });
});
```

This looks like a sloppy way to check for conditions, is there more `rxjs` way of doing this? I know that there is one using `combineLatest` and `forkJoin` both seems to be deprecated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick question, Can you get the data from server itself in that format? That is the preferred and easiest way.

Comment: @AnkitGarg, most times it may not be possible to get data in a desired format so we may need to transform it.

Comment: @AnkitGarg I can't. Both are being pulled from firebase and using the server just adds a delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const arr1$ = of([
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "id": "org1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "id": "org2"
  }
])
const arr2$ = of([
  {
    "organisation_id": "org1",
    "id": "unitId1"
  },
  {
    "organisation_id": "org30",
    "id": "UnitId2"
  }
]);

const arr3$ = combineLatest([arr1$, arr2$]).pipe(
  map(([arr1, arr2]) => {
    return arr1.map( item => ({
        name: item.name,
        id: item.id,
        units: arr2.filter(
          unit => unit.organisation_id === item.id
        )
      }))
    }
  )
)
```

NB: Please note to import `combineLatest` from `rxjs` and **NOT** `rxjs/operators`. `combineLatest` from `rxjs/operators` is deprecated but `combineLatest` from `rxjs` is not. The syntax is also important. `combineLatest(arr1$, arr1$)` is deprecated but `combineLatest([arr1$, arr2$])` is not deprecated

Comment: you are missing a comma near `id:`

Comment: I have an issue here. Using `of()` seems to be working, but when I get `Observable<Organisations[]>` I get a list at `item` but not object

Comment: could you console log arr1 and arr2 inside the map operator?

Comment: I have an object that shows `[{user_id: "fTVi4SPfTlUJ23a6rctbzjb6Cax1", name: "Apple", added_on: t, id: "74yctkqm45ndWUpo1kXr"}, ...]` There are optional keys. arr2 is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried one method based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51933015/3782963.

```
this.organisations.pipe(
    switchMap((orgList) => {
      return this.units.pipe(
        map((unitList) => {
          const combOrgUnit: OrganisationAndUnit[] = [];

          for (const org of orgList) {
            const tempComb: OrganisationAndUnit = {organisation: undefined, units: []};
            const tempUnit: Unit[] = [];
            tempComb.organisation = org;
            for (const unit of unitList) {
              if (org.id === unit.organisation_id) {
                tempUnit.push(unit);
                tempComb.units = tempUnit;
              }
            }
            combOrgUnit.push(tempComb);
          }

          return combOrgUnit;
        })
      );
    })
  ).subscribe(a => console.log(a));
```

Make sure to import `import {map, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`

But @OwenKelvin's answer is much better.